# Javascript code goes into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, loops

the following code goes into infinite loop and a crash in the webpage I need to know what's wrong with it?

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i+1) {
            for (var j = i; j < 8; j + 2) {
                console.log(arr[j].Qu);
            }
            console.log(arr[i]);
        }
```

Comment: and what do you try to achieve here, it is unclear, and why `j` equals `i` ?

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş I wanted to make nested loops based on each others for some business logic in my business

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i+1 doesn't update i's value, therefor, the i always has value 1, as it takes 0+1 in every run, thus never being > 2 and never ending
You need to change it with i++, like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
```

Also, as @Xufox points out, udpate your J loop with

```
for (var j = i; j < 8; j += 2) {
```

i+1 is not an assign operation, that's why you need to assign the value urself. `i++` and `j+=2` translate to

```
i = i+1;
j= j+2;
```

and the result of the righthand operation is self-assigned to the variable

Comment: Same for `j` which should be `j += 2`.

Comment: @moaatazaamer you've to assign the value back to `i` using assignment operator `i = i + 1` or use the increment operator `i++` which is short-cut for same.

Comment: @moaatazaamer `i + 1` will just return the value of `i + 1`. In order to save that value back into the variable you would have to do something like this : `i = i+1` or the shorthand version `i++`.

Comment: @moaatazaamer if it helped and fixed your erro, please remember to accept the answer.

Comment: yes of course I will, but why is that available on languages like C# ( i+1 )

Comment: That loop doesn't work in C# either, you also need the `i++` there or `i+=1`. Indeed, it throws a compiler error

Answer (score 1):

Value is not assigned back to variable.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 2; i+=1) { // i++
            for (var j = i; j < 8; j+=2) {
                console.log(arr[j].Qu);
            }
            console.log(arr[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`i+1` doesn't modify i value.
You could write instead `i++`.

Similarly, `j + 2` doesn't update j.
You should write `j += 2`.

Here is the corrected code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (var j = i; j < 8; j += 2) {
        console.log(arr[j].Qu);
    }
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i+=1) {
        for (var j = i; j < 8; j+= 2) {
            console.log(arr[j]);
        }
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe a short sentence which describes the change would be nice. :)
(its sometimes hard to spot the difference)